# Using MLFlow Tracking on isolated servers

Tags: mlflow

My question is not really technical. I want to determine if MLFlow is a way to go in my context.

I'd like our entire team to use mainly MLFlow tracking when training or finetuning large language models (NLP team / seq2seq models). My requirement is that I want to keep a record of all parameters and metrics (along with code version, etc.) accessible on a team server.

Most of the training/fine-tuning is done on powerful shared proprietary platform, but when running on the server nodes, there is no way to access the network. So, working with a shared MLFlow server deployed on an external machine is not possible.

I understand that in this setting MLFlow is still usable, locally, on disk.

What I would like to know is :

**Is there a way to a posteriori import several local backends into a common shared MLFlow server?**

The question would also be rephrased :

**How can we track experiments/trainings/finetunings locally, while still being able to share them with the rest of the team?**

Just like a `git push` for experiment logs done on a local clone to push everything to the common ML forge.

Comment: You are saying that this option does not work for your team https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/tracking/tutorials/remote-server.html, right? I am not entire sure what to do either, since I am also now considering how to use MLflow, but I think in its simplest form, MLflow is supposed to track experiments that are done/saved in the same place where Mflow UI will be launched. In theory the individual experiment outputs of the team could be copied to where the UI is, so it recognizes them. Also, perhaps some principles related to how MLflow deals with distributed training could be applied here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You use `log_model` and `log_artifacts` in your local training scripts to create, inside your artifact repository, inside the run's subdirectory, inside the `artifacts` subdirectory, everything you need to do inferencing:

- Your model (a subclass of `mlflow.{flavor}.{basemodel}`, most likely `mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel`)
- Your runtime-required code in a directory (or directories) you'll use with `code_paths`
- Artifacts in files that you'll associate with an `artifacts` dictionary.
- Your environment specification (perhaps, but not necessarily, a conda yaml file)

For instance:

```
# Some file you wish to become an artifact, such as a FAISS indexfile
faiss_index_filename = save_faiss_index(embeddings)
artifacts = { 
    "FaissIndex" : faiss_index_filename
    ... etc ... 
}

model_info = mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(
        artifact_path="pyfunc_artifacts",
        python_model=MyModelThatUsesFaiss(),
        artifacts=artifacts,
        code_path=code_paths,
        conda_env="../conda-ubuntu.yaml"
    )
```

In your model subclass you implement the `load_context` method to load the artifacts at runtime. For instance:

```
class MyModelThatUsesFaiss(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
   def load_context(self, context):
       self.index = faiss.read_index(context.artifacts["FaissIndex"])
       ... etc ...
   ... etc ...
```

After training, in your artifacts repo, you'll have `{project id}/{run_uuid}/artifacts/model/` which will contain your model and artifacts. You can share that directory to distant machines for inferencing:

```
model_dir = ... wherever ...
assert model_dir.exists(), f"Model directory {model_dir} does not exist"
model = mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_dir)
```

Comment: Well, I understand that I can get the artifacts from the artifacts folder. My specific question is more related to the MLFlow tracking backend, where are stored the hyper parameters and the history of measures.

Comment: The idea being: how can I have a *shared* MLFlow tracking server holding all the parameters/measures and taking its inputs from different local tracking directories (consolidated).

Comment: OK, I see what you’re saying. It’s significantly harder and not recommended (esp with enterprises with thousands of models) but you can store locally in a relational DB and batch-merge them later. *But* you *will* face issues with consistency merging projects (eg machine A creates new Project 235 and machine B creates another). Runs are ID’d by uuids but projects are not.